# Is there such a thing as a scalar absolute field?

Tags: notation, vectors, scientific-notation

I have a mathematical expression which I feel must be a better / more formal representation.

The best way I can think to describe it is as a "scalar absolute field" (but there maybe a better name for it).

$$
F = \lVert\int^{space}_s|\vec{V}|ds\rVert
$$

So you have a vector field V in a 3d space. For each point you integrate over all of space (similar to a gravitational or electromagnetic field) *but* vectors in opposite directions do not cancel, they add to the magnitude (i.e. you integrate the absolute of the vector). Then finally you want the scalar value, so you normalise the vector.

For context the python (numpy) code to express it is given say a 4-dimensional array `vec` (a 3D vector in 3D space) might be

```
xyz = np.array([np.sum(dimension) for dimension in np.abs(vec)])
field = np.sum(xyz**2, axis=0)**0.5
```

Example for gravitation (or charge) in a 2D space

- You have a mass $M_a$ at position $a$, exerting a force $\vec{F_a} = -3\hat{x} +3\hat{y}$ on point $p$.
- Next you have a force $M_b$ at position $b$, exerting a force $\vec{F_b} = +2\hat{x} +2\hat{y}$ on point $p$.
- The vector force at point $p$ is therefore $\vec{F_p} = \vec{F_a}+\vec{F_b} = -1\hat{x} +5\hat{y}$
- Meaning the absolute of the vector is $|\vec{F_p}| = 1\hat{x} + 5\hat{y}$, and normalising would give you the scalar of $\lVert\vec{F_p}\rVert = \sqrt{1^2+5^2} = \sqrt{26}$
- What I need is $|\vec{F_a}|+|\vec{F_b}| = (|-3|+|2|)\hat{x}+ (|3|+|2|)\hat{y} = 5\hat{x}+5\hat{y}$, which gives you the scalar $\lVert|\vec{F_p}|\rVert = \sqrt{5^2+5^2} = \sqrt{50}$

Comment: Isn't the "absolute" of the vector already a scalar? So you would already have a positive scalar value from the integral and there is no need to "normalise" it.

Comment: @DavidK I think I'm explaining poorly, so have added an example to make it concrete.

Comment: Please try to be more concrete defination of your notation!!!

Comment: Who said you absolute value commute?

Comment: Do you know triangle inequality of vectors?

Comment: After long period of your new discovery which is indeed mistakenly correct I understand, But only mistake you have done is  need to replace The equality by an inequality over the equation but I am not gonna tell you which direction i.e. \geq or \leq since it's your discovery I don't want to give you the precise !!! Figure it out and publish a paper cool!!! I had already done it though what you want to describe but this hint should be enough for you if you are little catchy and on Acknowledgement don't take my ID's name and stuff just put , just write MSE helps me a much!!! Regards

Comment: A final Remark and this is my last comment on MSE, I.e try to genaral ize it and see the magic!!!

Comment: @user297148 - In many contexts, taking the absolute values of a vector's coordinates is an unnatural operation (unlike scalar multiplication or vector addition). You'll get different results if you rotate the coordinate system. Things in geometry or physics shouldn't depend on the coordinate system used.

Comment: Direct Sum is the key!!! Instead of using $+$ used direct sum while defining it or some inequality notation as a relation!!! You are actually defining  relation !!!! So you should do it like define it in such a way!!! Then it all makes sense even in the generalized version of n-coordinate!!! Now investigate what type of relation is this , if it's new give it a name if it's old named it as usual.

Comment: So let me Illustrate how you summed up the things.

Comment: I see what you mean now but I agree with mr_e_man. It’s hard to imagine an application where this idea makes any sense. Maybe you should ask someone about the problem you were working on **before** you got the idea to apply this method to it, and see if there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @mr_e_man, you're right. However, those weren't coordinates in the example, it was poor notation again, so I've updated the example.

Comment: You've changed the notation from $\vec F=(x,y)$ to $\vec F=x\hat x+y\hat y$. I'd still call $x$ and $y$ coordinates. You could call them components or coefficients with respect to the basis $\{\hat x,\hat y\}$ or something else; it doesn't matter. My point remains the same.

Comment: Suppose $\vec F=-3\hat x+4\hat y$; then we have $|\vec F|=3\hat x+4\hat y$, which is different from $\vec F$ because $-3\neq3$. Now rotate the coordinate system by $90^\circ$, changing the basis vectors to $$\hat x'=\hat y,\quad\hat y'=-\hat x.$$ Thus $\vec F=4\hat x'+3\hat y'$, which implies that $|\vec F|=\vec F$ according to this coordinate system. So, is $\vec F=|\vec F|$, or not?

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you @mr_e_man

Answer (score 1):

Define ,$\vec{F}=\sum_{i}^{n} {F_{i}}\vec{e_{i}}$
We define the relation, for for vectors as , $|\vec{F}|=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}|{F_{i}}|\vec{e_{i}}$ where absolute value defined by op.
Now, tried to think of giving a structure it is indeed possible.Now go on as you wish,
Next for continuous case you can think of like breaking the component in Riemann Sum or Some integrable sum and apply the direct sum unless you cannot define it in continuous case , now think to give it a new notation (cool)!!!
Best Regards!!!